# R object with or wihtout quotes

Tags: r

Let's say I want to create a function, that takes a dataframe

```
data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3])
```

and a column name and returns the respective column. Now, I want the function to return the column regardless of whether I pass the column name with or without quotation marks, i.e. as a string or as a (non-existent) object.

```
foo1 <- function(df, column){
    df[[deparse(substitute(column))]]
}

foo2 <- function(df, column){
    df[[column]]
}

foo1(a)
foo2("a")
```

Both return

```
c(1,2,3)
```

but how can I do it in one function? I can't manage the testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `deparse()` is that if the  arguments has quotes (eg. "a"), they are kept in the output. `as.character()` converts its arguments to text if they aren't text and keep them as is if they are text. So

```
foo <- function(df, column){
    df[[as.character(substitute(column))]]
}
```

seems to do what you want.